# Checkmark in gridview appears on random item

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin.android

I am coding my application in C# (using monodroid) but I think this question can be applies to regular android java to.

I have a gridview and if the user touches a tile or item I want a checkmark to appear, if they touch a checked tile I want the checkmark to disappear. The problem I am having is the if the user touches a tile then scrolls down the checkmark will appear on random tiles. I know this has something to do with the fact that android recycles views but I cant figure out how to fix it.

Here is my gridview `getview()` method

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        File f = files[position];

       ViewHolder holder;

       if (convertView == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
           convertView = li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.gallery_item, parent, false) as LinearLayout;

           holder = new ViewHolder();

           holder.iv = convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.ivGalleryItem) as ImageView;
           holder.iv.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);

           holder.ivCheck = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivCheck);

           convertView.SetTag(Resource.Layout.gallery_item, holder);
```

//  ********Here is where i say if the user touches a tile show a checkmark and set this tile to true for checked*

```
           holder.iv.Click += delegate
           {

               if (isChecked[position])
               {
                   holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                   isChecked[position] = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                   isChecked[position] = true;
               }

           };
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.GetTag(Resource.Layout.gallery_item);
       }


// **************************here is wherere I say if the tile is true than show the checkmark if it is false dont show it
       if (isChecked[position])
       {
           holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
       }
       else
       {
           holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
       }

       if (f.Exists() && f.IsFile)
       {
           getPhotoTask.getphoto(holder.iv, f);
       }
       else
       {
           holder.iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.boostitred);
       }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you are only setting click listeners for the first items that are visible on screen; `convertView != null` when you scroll to reveal other items. 
This means that clicking on some of your grid items (those that started off screen and later came on screen) will modify your `isChecked` array incorrectly.

For example, say you have 12 grid items visible on screen right at first. When the `GridView` calls `getView` for the first time, `convertView == null`, so your code creates a new `View` (a `LinearLayout` in this case), a new `ViewHolder`, and assigns a click listener for Views with positions 0 - 11. When you scroll, the `GridView` starts recycling views that are now off screen in order to create the new views coming on screen. In these cases, `convertView != null`, so your code is not setting a click listener.

I think the simple fix looks like this:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    File f = files[position];

   ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView == null)
   {
       LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
       convertView = li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.gallery_item, parent, false) as LinearLayout;

       holder = new ViewHolder();

       holder.iv = convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.ivGalleryItem) as ImageView;
       holder.iv.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);

       // *Here is where i say if the user touches a tile show a checkmark and set this tile to true for checked
       holder.ivCheck = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivCheck);

       convertView.SetTag(Resource.Layout.gallery_item, holder);

   }
   else
   {
       holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.GetTag(Resource.Layout.gallery_item);
   }

   holder.iv.Click += delegate
   {

       if (isChecked[position])
       {
           holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
           isChecked[position] = false;
       }
       else
       {
           holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
           isChecked[position] = true;
       }

   };

  // **************************here is wherere I say if the tile is true than show the checkmark if it is false dont show it
   if (isChecked[position])
   {
       holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
   }
   else
   {
       holder.ivCheck.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
   }

   if (f.Exists() && f.IsFile)
   {
       getPhotoTask.getphoto(holder.iv, f);
   }
   else
   {
       holder.iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.boostitred);
   }

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see, I've simply moved the setting of your `Click` delegate outside of the initial if/else.

However, in Android world, we'd normally not set click listeners in the adapter at all. Instead, `GridView`, and any `AdapterView` for that matter, has a method called `setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)`. That method will be called whenever a grid item is clicked. At that point, you'd be able to update your `isChecked` array, which could, for example, be a member of the `Fragment` rather than the adapter.